# QString::number() 'f' format without trailing zeros

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I want to convert number to `QString` with 3 significant digits.

```
QString::number(myNumber,'f',3);
```

does the job but remains trailing zeros. How to use it without them.

Also I've tried `'g'` and which shouldn't remain those zeros:

```
QString::number(myNumber,'g',3);
```

but  for example 472.76 is converted to 473. That surprised me. Why is it so with `'g'` option?

**However I am interested in `'f'` format. So the main question is how to do it with `'f'` without trailing zeros?**

Input -> Desired output

472.76 -> 472.76

0.0766861 -> 0.077

180.00001 -> 180

Comment: Can you give examples for input and your desired output?

Comment: I've added some. I don't want trailing zeros. And the maximum number of digits after decimal point is 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm almost embarrassed to post this but it works:

```
QString toString( qreal num )
{
    QString str = QString::number( num, 'f', 3 );

    str.remove( QRegExp("0+$") ); // Remove any number of trailing 0's
    str.remove( QRegExp("\\.$") ); // If the last character is just a '.' then remove it

    return str;
}
```

If you're really concerned about the performance using this method you may want to come up with a different solution.

Comment: It's wrong. Second conversion to number takes double with default 'g', 6. So for big number it will write them as exponential. Tested with 1000000000.2023 and returns 1e+09.

Comment: I changed my answer to use an alternate solution, which is equally unpretty but seems to work.

Comment: Can you add what thas RegExp do as clarification? I've also thought about parsing and removing those zeros manually. It's pitty that such elementar thing cannot be done with framework.

Comment: Sure I added a couple of comments

Comment: His solution doesn't account for all of the cases that the original question presents.

Comment: Embarrasing for Qt. This seems to be a bug. With 'e/E' precision is equivalent to significants, with 'f' its equivalent to digits after comma.

Comment: You can use only one regExp:
 str.remove( QRegExp("\\.?0+$") );

Comment: Wrong. 200 return 2.

Comment: @l2m2 200 won't occur because of the 'f' argument with 3 decimal precision.

Comment: @sleepysilverdoor you're right. thanks for reply.

Comment: The "?" is not needed: str.remove( QRegExp("\\.0+$") );

Answer (score 5):

```
QString::number(myNumber,'g',3);
```

Will limit the conversion to the significant digits. You'll most always have 3 numbers.

```
472.76 => 472
4.7276 => 4.72
```

Try using the formatted printing functions like `QString::sprintf`. This should give you more control.

```
QString numStr;
numStr.sprintf("f.3f", myNumber);
```

Comment: Missing % in numStr.sprintf("%f.3f", myNumber);

Comment: Should be sprintf("%.3f", myNumber);

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to have the precision after the decimal point you have to use `'f'`. Here is an option to remove the trailing zeors with better performance than the Regex using only QString builtins:

```
QString str = QString::number(myNumber,'f',3);
while(str.back() =='0')
{
    str.chop(1);
}
if(str.back() =='.')
{
    str.chop(1);
}
```

This works because the f option guarantees to put out the defined digits.
It's about 50% faster than C sprintf and 40% faster than QString::sprintf from the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString str;
str.setNum(myNumber, 'f', 3);
```

This will do what you need, I tested it. Strangely, "number" behaves differently than "setNum".

Comment: It remains zeros. For example 472.76000 is converted to 472.760 and should be 472.76. Works for me the same as number.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. It is maybe more performant than the variant with regular expressions.
The mynumber() function takes a new format char 'h', which does the job.

```
QString mynumber(qreal p_number, char p_format, int p_precision)
{
    if(p_format=='h')
    {
        //like 'f' but removes trailing zeros and the '.' evtl
        QString res=QString::number(p_number,'f',p_precision);
        int countTrailingToRemove=0;
        for(QString::const_reverse_iterator it=res.crbegin();it!=res.crend();it++)
        {
            if(*it=='0') countTrailingToRemove++;
            else
            {
                if(*it=='.') countTrailingToRemove++;
                break;
            }
        }

        return res.mid(0,res.length()-countTrailingToRemove);
    }
    return QString::number(p_number,p_format,p_precision);

}
```